# Getting error while submit sign transaction

Tags: wallet, cardano-address, ada

I am try to submitting sign transaction on Rosetta (https://ada-rosetta.nownodes.io/construction/submit) but, each time getting below error.
TTL is already higher than slot.

Request

```
{
    "network_identifier": {
        "blockchain": "cardano",
        "network": "mainnet"
    },
    "signed_transaction": "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"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "code": 5003,
    "message": "Parse signed transaction error",
    "retriable": false
}
```